Unity registers two touches even with multitouch disabled
In my 2D project, the multitouch is disabled, but when I move the finger to the edge of the screen, the multitouch seems to be enabled again. When I move the finger to the edge of the screen while holding the finger, I could use another finger to interact with the game.
(interestingly, it only happens near the left, right and bottom edge, not the top edge).
According to my tests, this only occurs on the iPhone and won’t happen on the Android platform. Also, I'm assuming this has something to do with the notch screen device (like iPhone X), because the same problem doesn't happen on an iPad. We don't have any none-notch screen device, so my assumption might be wrong.
FYI, when dealing with the input in mobile devices, I'm using Input.Touches to get the touch.
Does anyone has any clue what might happen?
P.S. after a little bit of investigation, I think it has something to do with the safeArea. When the finger touched inside the safe area moved out of the safe area, but not letting go, I can use another finger to touch and Unity will register that extra touch event. But I am still confused about why this would happen.
